# Shooting down helicopters in Battlefield Bad Company 2: Vietnam

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam

I dont know if anyone else out there has noticed but the Helicopters in Bad Company 2: Vietnam are stupidly hard to shoot down.

I consider myself quite a Veteran at the original Bad Company 2 where heli's weren't all that much of a problem with the tracer dart and rpg combo, but I am really struggling with them in Vietnam.

Currently I just chip away slowly with an LMG and hope they dont fly off the get healed. Is there something incredibly obvious that I am missing ? because its just plain ridicolous how much damage these things can do sometimes (even if the pilot isnt anything special).

Comment: You might be able to pick on some tactics from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQmIz2CbDks&feature=share

Comment: As I said in my post im only interested in the Heli's in the vietnam expansion. The video you linked is only using the M136 AT4 which in unavailable in Vietnam. Helis are a piece of piss in regular bad company 2 with the tracer dart / rpg combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hands of a good pilot Huey is pretty much indestructible if it keeps healing after a few cycles (they could even heal it right in the air). If I jump into one I would be dead in 10 seconds, but I still remember one guy that was murdering our whole team for the whole game  scoring >4k points (and taking down choppers is my highest priority).

The best you can do is to spot it as early as possible and hope that a few teammates start helping, single handed you can only be somewhat an annoyance to a good pilot forcing him to go for a repair after couple cycles. To take cycle strafing armored chopper down in one cycle you probably would need at least 3 people with LMGs.

If I am the only one who tries to take it down, then the safest strategy against a good pilot is to shoot only when the chopper is turned backwards to you, and then quickly move to a new position before the next cycle. LMG seems to work the best.

Answer (score 2):

The medic's LMG is too weak to cause serious damage, even if three medics are shooting at the chopper. Every pilot can fly to a safe zone and repair his vehicle.

The best weapon to bring down an enemy heli is the main gun of a tank. RPGs have similar effects, but are more difficult to aim (slow...).
If you are also flying a Huey, use your doorgunners to take out the pilot.

The PBR patrol boat also does a lot of damage to the Huey; not enough to destroy it, but enough to keep it away most of the time.

Comment: Good shout on the PBR, never thought of that :)

Answer (score 1):

I always shoot at the driver when trying to take down the choppers. The Huey's may have a lot of life on their own but the bullets go right through the windshield or side and kill the driver quite easily. I have even done it with the pistol :P. Overall though I haven't noticed the choppers have that much health, it seems like every time I get in one someone takes it out with an SMG or assault rifle in under a minute, maybe I'm just a bad driver...